# Relationship between SC and NL

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, space-complexity

It is a major open problem whether $NL \subseteq SC$, or equivalently, whether directed reachability can be solved (simultaneously) in poly-logarithmic space and polynomial time. What is known regarding $SC \subseteq NL$?

It would show $L\subseteq SC \subseteq NL \subseteq P\cap polyL \subseteq P$, but can we anything else?

Comment: This would imply that for arbitrarily large constant $k$, $\mathrm{TISP}(n^{O(1)},(\log n)^k)\subseteq\mathrm{DSPACE}((\log n)^2)$. There is no version of the space hierarchy theorem to unconditionally rule this out, but it would be quite surprising.